# Bar graph created using plot() function in r has y axis values that are greater than what is there in the data set

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am learning different visualisations in r and was plotting x vs y in a sample data. The max y value is 105.59 and when I plotted this data set in a scatter plot, I got the plot within range. When I tried plotting as bar graphs, y value is showing 400+.

My code is:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = test_data$x, y = test_data$y),
             colour = 'red', size=2) 
            colour = 'purple', size=2) +
  ggtitle('X vs Y for Test data set') +
  xlab('X') +
  ylab('Y')
```

[output for geom_point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DtEX.png)

```
ggplot(test_data,aes(x = x, y = y))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  ggtitle('X vs Y for Test data set') +
  xlab('X') +
  ylab('Y')
```

[output for geom_bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZbso.png)

I was expecting a bar chart with x value max at 105.59 and not 400+
I saw a similar question heer([Y axis values are greater than actual values in geom_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66253984/y-axis-values-are-greater-than-actual-values-in-geom-bar)), but my data has only 2 columns x and y and no other categories as in that answer

Comment: 1) Don't do this: `aes(x = test_data$x, y = test_data$y)`, put the data frame outside `aes()` as in the other call to ggplot; 2) it seems that `geom_bar` is adding the y values, try `geom_col` instead.

Comment: the geom_point were i put the data frame inside aes() is working perfectly, problem is with the second set of code. and yes, i tried geom_col, its giving the same result as geom_bar. I also tried geom_line and its working fine.

Comment: Are all the values in x unique? If not, y-axis values get summed/stacked for duplicate x-axis values. I'm guessing your x-axis values are integers?

Comment: x values are integers but not unique. https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/andonians/random-linear-regression this is my data set( test.csv)

Comment: With `geom_bar`, when 2 bars are on top of each other (same x values) the default is to stack them on top of each other. At the `?geom_bar` help page you can see the default `position = 'stack'`. If you don't want this behavior you can set `geom_bar(position = 'identity', stat = 'identity')`.